# A part of script in js file worked correctly with firebug console but not worked in page

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebug

I am really confusing, I have a js file with a lot of scripts, all of them worked correctly and I just add new lines:

```
$('.RemoveE').click(function () {
    alert('yap');
});
```

but that not worked, I test it with firebug and every things is OK, also I try another browsers that not worked either, I must mention that I add new button with CSS class `="ReomoveE button red"` by script, this is a part of my js include new lines and add button:

```
// <reference path="../jquery-1.7.1.js" />
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.RemoveE').click(function() {
        alert('yap');
    });

    //Add new Addable div
    $('.AddNewE').click(function() {

        var Target = $('.Addable:first');
        var TargetId = $(Target).attr('id');
        var Count = $('.Addable#' + TargetId).size();
        var CloneTarget = $(Target).clone();
        CloneTarget.find('input').val('');
        CloneTarget.insertAfter('.Addable:last');
        var TargetName = $(Target).find('input').attr('name');
        var CloneName = TargetName + '[1]';
        TargetName = TargetName + '[0]';
        $(Target).find('input').attr('name', TargetName);
        $(Target).find('span[class*="field-validation"]').attr('data-valmsg-for', TargetName);
        $(CloneTarget).find('input').attr('name', CloneName);
        $(CloneTarget).append($('<input type="button" class="RemoveE button red" value="remove" />'));

        (function($) {
            $.fn.updateValidation = function() {
                var form = this.closest("form").removeData("validator").removeData("unobtrusiveValidation");
                $.validator.unobtrusive.parse(form);
                return this;
            };
        })(jQuery);

        $(Target).updateValidation();
        $(CloneTarget).updateValidation();
    });
    ...
});​
```

So what do you think? Where is the problem, why all functions worked correctly, but this new one no?

Comment: when you load the page in your browser, you should look at Firebug to see if it gives you any error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You added the handler before the element existed:

```
$('.RemoveE').click(function() {
    alert('yap');
});

//then later

$(CloneTarget).append($('<input type="button" class="RemoveE button red" value="remove" />'));
```

Try:

Adding the handler on creation:

```
var newInput = $('<input type="button" class="RemoveE button red" value="remove" />')

newInput.click(function(){
    alert('yap');
});

$(CloneTarget).append(newInput)
```

or delegation with `on()`

```
$(parent_of_RemoveE).on('click','.RemoveE',function() {
    alert('yap');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, your way cause a new problem, If I deine button as `newInput` and then use it as `$(CloneTarget).append(newInput)` then when I click on `.AddNewE` just move `RemoveE` button, it means I just have one `RemoveE` button in page all time, but I need to create new one by click `.AddNewE`

Comment: @Saeid you declare the `newInput` inside the click handler of `AddNewE`. That way, it creates a new input everytime.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `.on()` or `.delegate()` so it can listen to any new button that you created dynamically

See the sample code here

HTML

​`<div id='test'></div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​`

JQUERY

```
​$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('#test').on('click','.removeE', function() {
     alert('yap');
    });

    $('#test').append('<input type="button" class="removeE" value="test"/>');
});​
```

you can see the example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/7KGwJ/)

Answer (score 1):

What **@Joseph** said basically. I commented your code bit to point out some things worth noting.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.RemoveE').click(function () {
        alert('yap');
    });

    //Add new Addable div
    $('.AddNewE').click(function () {

        var Target = $('.Addable:first');
        var TargetId = $(Target).attr('id'); // Double wrapping in jQuery

         // ID are unique, selector makes little sense,
         // and `length` is preferable to `size()`
        var Count = $('.Addable#' + TargetId).size();
        var CloneTarget = $(Target).clone(); // Double wrapping in jQuery
        CloneTarget.find('input').val('');
        CloneTarget.insertAfter('.Addable:last');
        var TargetName = $(Target).find('input').attr('name'); // Double wrapping in jQuery

        // This seems a bit verbose...
        var CloneName = TargetName + '[1]';
        TargetName = TargetName + '[0]';
        $(Target).find('input').attr('name', TargetName); // Double wrapping in jQuery
        $(Target).find('span[class*="field-validation"]').attr('data-valmsg-for', TargetName); // Double wrapping in jQuery
        $(CloneTarget).find('input').attr('name', CloneName); // Double wrapping in jQuery
        $(CloneTarget).append($('<input type="button" class="RemoveE button red" value="remove" />')); // Double wrapping in jQuery
        // end verbosity

        (function ($) {
            $.fn.updateValidation = function () {
                // Don't need to chain `removeData()` twice,
                // as of jQuery 1.7 you can pass a list
                var form = this.closest("form").removeData("validator").removeData("unobtrusiveValidation");
                $.validator.unobtrusive.parse(form);
                return this;
            };
        })(jQuery);

        $(Target).updateValidation(); // Double wrapping in jQuery
        $(CloneTarget).updateValidation(); // Double wrapping in jQuery
    });

});
```